# The nth derivative of $x^a$

Tags: derivatives

I've three cases with $f(x)=x^a$:

$$\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}\left(x^a\right)=\begin{cases}a!\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n=a\\
0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n>a\\
b\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n<a
\end{cases}$$

To find $b$, I did:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^a\right)=ax^{a-1}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(x^a\right)=a(a-1)x^{a-2}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^3}{\text{d}x^3}\left(x^a\right)=a(a-1)(a-2)x^{a-3}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}x^4}\left(x^a\right)=a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)x^{a-4}$$

But how I find the general way?

Answer (score 0):

The first four instances you already gave, are generalized as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\left(x^a\right)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}{(a-i)}\ \cdot\ x^{a-n}$$
for $n<a$.

Comment: btw, note that splitting into the three cases is not even necessary, as the above formula also gives the right result for $n\geq a$.

Comment: If $n > a$ and $a$ is not an integer you do need the splitting.

Comment: $a$ needs to be integer, you're right. But I don't get the _if_ $n>a$ part of your comment? Then you're already splitting...

Comment: I just made the distinction because for $a\leq n$ your formula is correct even if $a$ is not an integer.

Comment: @DarthGeek, ah okay. You are correct! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use induction. Note that for the $n$-th derivative you have a product of constants from $a$ to $a-(n-1)$ and an exponent $a-n$ for $x$.